Page linking issue
I have the following navigation items: Home, About Us, Services, and Contact.
Under the Services menu, I have two sub-menu items: 1. Business Analysis and 2. Training Management. I have created separate pages for each of these items and added the corresponding links in the navigation menu.
However, the issue I am facing is that when I click on the "Contact" link, it displays the content for "About Us" instead.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
